# Users should log in (moodle)

Tags: moodle

I want that my users have to log in into moodle before they can see anything. So they should only see the login screen and no more. Where can I set these settings into Moodle?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the checkbox Force users to log in found in "Site administration > Security > Site policies".

Depending on moodle version, site policies might be located somewhere else, but this should do the job